# React + mobx object keeps getting updated

Tags: reactjs, mobx

The problem I am having is that I have an object which is used throughout entire class which is stored under the observable value and I have another object which is stored as a back up of the first object and the value is non observable and its created in the constructor (same problem if I create outside constructor as non observable value). For example:

```
some class{

    @observable people = some object value

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.oldValue = {}
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){
        this.oldValue = this.people
    }

}
```

Now if people object gets updated, lets say the value is changed, `this.oldValue` will be updated as well for some reason even thought it should not. If I set `this.oldValue` variable to a string and then give the value like so `this.oldValue = object.name` then the old value will not going to be updated as expected.

What can cause the problem? Why is the value being updated when its set as object and not when the string?

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't make a whole lot of sense after re-reading your problem. Can you post a snippet that physically demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Well in the code the structure is the same as in my pseudo-code. Sorry I cant post any code as the class is huge and due to work copyright

Comment: Assigning `this.oldValue` to `this.people` *should* dereference the observable property and just copy the value once. The docs explain this quite nicely [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html#don-t-copy-observables-properties-and-store-them-locally). Can't comment further without some actual code.

Comment: Well thats what I thought but it doesnt. It looks like it makes a copy of the same object with the refferences just with a different variable which gets updated as well as original's values

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by cloning the object instead of assigning it. For example instead of:

```
this.oldValue = this.currentValue
```

I used [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone) library to clone:

```
this.oldValue = _.clone(this.currentValue)
```

So even if `this.currentValue` values being updated, `this.oldValue`values are staying intact for the future ref

I presume my problem was that I created same object with same references for updates with a different variable

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but I reckon re-assigning `observable` value is not the way `mobx` designed to be.

If your `oldValue` needs to be derived from the `observable` data, use `computed` for it.

Mobx author himself recommends against copy the observable data and store them locally: https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html#don-t-copy-observables-properties-and-store-them-locally.

Comment: Well I cant think of any other way to have an old values of the object which is being updated as I need the original values to have in order to check for the changes, but I cant do it as the object is keeps updating

Comment: It says that copying observable data will not be tracked and thats what i need, but its still being tracked and updated